# Large words showing wrong in phone view

Tags: html, css

I have a text with one large word and it's broke the phone view.
Please see the picture attached.

[picture here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kRcUq.png)

Comment: What is the question?

Answer (score 0):

apply the `word-wrap` CSS property on your content

```
* { word-wrap: break-word }
```

you'll better off if you are a bit more specific with your selector instead of '*' like:

```
p { word-wrap: break-word }
```

this will allow the long word(s) to be broken and wrapped onto the next line.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this, just apply the CSS to the text container.

```
.word-wrap {
  word-wrap: break-word; /* IE 5.5-7 */
  white-space: -moz-pre-wrap; /* Firefox 1.0-2.0 */
  white-space: pre-wrap; /* current browsers */
  }
```